# Postgresql is changing parameter definition from text[][] to text[]

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating a function like

```
create function a(layers_groups text[][]) returns void as
  $$
  ...
  $$ language plpgsql
```

and when I execute the script postgresql is changing the parameter definition to

```
create function a(layers_groups text[]) returns void as
      $$
      ...
      $$ language plpgsql
```

Anyone knows why is this happening. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) "*The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of dimensions either. Arrays of a particular element type are all considered to be of the same type, regardless of size or number of dimensions*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I were doing some research and it is like @a_horse_with_no_name quote from postgresql docs. I believe based on my tests that postgresql store and deal with array from n dimensions like it where from 1 dimension. These were my tests.

```
create or REPLACE  FUNCTION f(d text[][]) returns void as
$$
DECLARE
  g text;
BEGIN
  raise notice '%',d[1][1];
  raise notice 'Array iteration'
  FOREACH g in ARRAY d LOOP
    raise notice '%',g;
  END LOOP;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
select f('{{1,2},{3,4}}')
```

And the console outputs:

```
1
Array iteration
1
2
3
4
```